# "svn checkout" after "svnadmin load":

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump

I followed the steps [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/665.cfm) to dump and load a SVN repository.  I now have a repository called "newrepo" and I would like to check it out.  So, I do a "svnserve -d" and then a "svn checkout file:///newrepo newcheckout" and I get the following error:

```
$ svn checkout file:///newrepo newcheckout
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///newrepo'
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///newrepo'
```

(This is in Cygwin in Windows 10; the repository is a dump from a VisualSVN server on Windows 7.)

I'm probably missing some the path after newrepo but it's been some time since I used the old repository.  Can I find that with "snvlook tree" or some such?  Assuming I get the path, what other steps do I need do?

Any help would be much appreciated!  Ultimately, I want to migrate the repository to GitHub.

Comment: Wrong URL. file:/// is not the scheme to use with svnserve.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment on your question says, you are mixing two different kinds of access to the repository. Accessing the repository with `file:///` will require you to enter the full path your repository, something like `file:///C:/mysvnfolder/newrepo`.

But if you want to use `svnserve` (for example, you want to be able to check out this repository from other computer in the network), you need to use the right protocol as well: something like `svn checkout svn://localhost/newrepo`. Notice that the URI here starts with "svn" and not "file".

Note that these examples will not actually work if you just copy and paste them, but I cannot provide a fully working example without knowing more details about your setup.